# Looking for a buddy for studying QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, education

I'm in the middle of the 1st QFT course (following Peskin&Schroesder and some lecture notes). It's rather a hobby (have a full time job in a different area + family). It would be really nice to have someone to discuss, think, solve problems etc.
Looking forward to hearing from someone crazy to have such a hobby :)
TvZ

Comment: A little more detail pls.?
am kind of intersted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about physics. PSE is not a “find a study buddy” site.

Comment: You can make a chat room and invite interested people over there to have a chat or just visit [The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: Sometimes this site is a bit limited in its rules imo, but it is what it is, you can try physicsforums. If you start doing QCD/electroweak stuff I would be interested: doublefelix921@gmail.com . Feel free to also ask a question here and there, I spent a lot of time understanding the general structure of QFT

Comment: OP feel free to start a chat with me and ask me any questions you have. It is a shame that your question got closed, sometimes following the rules to the book is like that... Don’t let it discourage you, feel free to ask questions about the actual physics/math here!